# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:3005)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, nullpointerexception

I moved today to macOS and recreated a very simple database-test project to check my mySQL connection. But i get an SQL Exception: "Could not create connection to database server". Here is the full log: https://pastebin.com/iZrktVKn

I literally copied every step, what i did on Windows. On Windows everything was fine. I have one context.xml, one Servlet, and one connector.jar file. This project should run on Tomcat.

**context.xml:**

```
<Context>

  <Resource name="jdbc/web_student_tracker" 
            auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000"
               username="webstudent" password="webstudent" 
               driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker?useSSL=false"/>

</Context>
```

**Servlet(just the important things):**

```
        @Resource(name="jdbc/web_student_tracker")
        private DataSource dataSource;
```

doGet method in Servlet:

```
        //Printwiter + content type setting
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");

        //Get a connection to the database
        Connection myConn = null;
        Statement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;

        try{
            myConn = dataSource.getConnection();

            //Create SQL statements
            String sql = "select * from student";
            myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

            //Execute SQL query
            myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);

            //Process the ResultSet
            while(myRs.next()) {
                String email = myRs.getString("email");
                out.println(email);
            }


        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

**And i did add a 'webstudent'user to the DB:**

```
CREATE USER 'webstudent'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'webstudent';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'webstudent'@'localhost';
```

Everything is up and running, what im i missing? Also im new to developing in macOS, and also new to MySQL. But on Windows, everything worked just fine.

**StackTrace:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server.)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2333)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2062)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
    at com.jsptanulas.web.jdbc.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:40)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:917)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2085)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:327)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:260)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2343)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2329)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:3005)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1916)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1845)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1215)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2255)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2286)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace in your question. Do not use external links for pertinent information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was the connector version and the MySQL version mismatch. MySQL 8 needs the version 8 from the JDBC connector .jar .

Comment: Recent version of MySQL Connector/J 5.1 also work with MySQL 8 (eg MySQL Connector/J 5.1.46)

Comment: my case i used <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
        </dependency> instead of    <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

It is because of version mismatch of mysql connector jar. Change version or dependency of mysql

Answer (score 0):

For the next person that has this problem using Spring Boot and a properties file: For me it was because I had a bunch of spaces next to the database connection.